# How to define a JSON type?

Tags: c#, json

What I'm trying to do something like this, I know it won't work:

```
using JSON<object> = Dictionary<string, object>;
```

How can I write a code that does what I mean in the example above? I want to use it with this simple syntax:

```
JSON<int> json = { {"key", 123} };

// And it equals to
Dictionary<string, int> JSON = new Dictionary<string, int> { {"key", 123} };
```

Comment: `class JSON<T> :  Dictionary<string, T> { }`? You've said nothing about how you're going to use this type, of course. How are you going to get data into it?

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish here with this syntax? Typically you would define your C# code using C# types, and then convert to / from JSON using JSON.NET or a similar library. What's your use case here?

Comment: @ChrisTavares I created a function that takes an argument as this JSON type. And I don't want to allow another type than a string as the type of key. Yeah maybe there can be more efficient ways to implement this, why I use a Dictionary here is I've seen that from another thread.

Comment: And I use simply `JSON<object> some_json = new JSON<object> { {"key", "value"}, {"key", 123} };` to combine different types of entries.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what passing JSON<T> buys you over just passing the Dictionary<string, T> instead? What does the JSON part get you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a generic type and inheritance.

```
public class JSON<T> : Dictionary<string, T> {  
}
```

Usage:

```
JSON<int> json = new JSON<int>{ {"key", 123} };
```